# how to customize rightclick on chrome devtools elements panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[devtools elements panel right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sufm3.png)

look at the image above. right clicking on any node displays menu of options like 'add attribute' and  'edit attribute' etc...

I want to be able to extend the right click menu to add my custom events. 
for example, I need to get the xpath of the node. 
I know I can extend the right click on actual page instead of extending right click on the source of the page.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#type-ElementsPanel
API's only supports selection change.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the [Extending DevTools API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#type-ElementsPanel) doesn't expose the context menu from the internal DevTools source code. Sometimes the API documentation omits some available functions/properties, so I confirmed this with:

```
alert(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(chrome.devtools.panels.elements));
```

It returned `onSelectionChanged,createSidebarPane` only, which matches the documentation.

The WebInspector object in the DevTools source code has a `populateNodeContextMenu` function on `WebInspector.ElementsTreeElement.prototype`,  but this cannot be accessed through the Extending DevTools API. It is completely separate.

[image]