# "Save as" from Google chrome Developer Tools Network tab missing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I right click an entry in the network tab in google chromes developer tools network tab, I get theese alternatives:

- Copy (open a sub menu with Copy Link Address, Copy Request headers, Copy Response headers, Copy response, Copy as cURL (cmd), Copy as cURL (bash), Copy all as cURL (cmd), Copy all as cURL (bash), Copy all as HAR)
- Save as HAR with content
- Clear browser cache
- Clear browser cookies
- Block request URL
- Block request Domain
- Open in Sources panel
- Open in new tab

## Questions

- Where is "Save as"?
- Can I customize this menu to remove unneeded entries?
- Is the pluginability letting me do those things?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22955932/632951

Comment: Use firefox, you cant save all resources once but one by one you can save

Comment: I found that for resources like images, css (and more to find out). There is a "Save as" option. But for some other type of resources, the "Save as" is missing and I have to copy the response content manually and save it to a local file bymyself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the whole list of requests/responses by using 'Save as HAR with content', but you can't save an individual one.

As for customising the context menu on the Network panel, or any other built-in panel, this isn't possible. I answered a similar question on the Elements panel last year, and found, after looking at the source code, that there were no hooks available. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050351

You can create context menus on custom panels, via [chrome.contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus). The Network panel has an API that exposes the requests data ([getHar](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network#method-getHAR)). You *could* perhaps build your own DevTools panel based on this data.

Comment: However <Save as HAR with content> will fail when there's too many requests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46697450/632951